# Matrix Mapping from R2 to R3. Determine matrix and size question?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear mapping from $\Bbb R^2$
to $\Bbb R^3$
.
$T$ is represented by a matrix $A$ (‘standard matrix’).
What is the size of this matrix? Determine
$A$ if we know that

$$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }T\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Please show your own attempts at solving this. To give you an answer you’ll understand, we have to know where you’re coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns of the standard matrix are given by 
$$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right),T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
Now use linearity to find 
$$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)=
T\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1\\2\end{bmatrix}\right)-T\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$
and 
$$
T\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right)=
T\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1\\2\end{bmatrix}\right)-2T\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)
$$

Comment: So would this result in two matricies?

Comment: @user3701380 no. Please look in the section on linear transformations in the linear algebra textbook you are using

Comment: @user3701380 this section will tell you how to build a matrix from a linear transformation. It will be nearly impossible to find help until you know the basics of this process